# Acute triangles from 100 points

Tags: discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given $n$ points in general position in the plane, let $P_n$ be the maximum proportion of the $\binom{n}{3}$ triangles with three acute angles. What is the limit $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n$?

An upper bound of $\frac{7}{10}$ is shown in the proof of the sixth question of the 1970 edition of the International Mathematical Olympiad.

In the opposite direction, we can establish a trivial lower bound of $5/9$ by spreading the points at $A$ so they are on a circle, centre $B$; the points at $B$ so they are on a circle, centre $C$, and the points at $C$ are on a circle centre $A$.  If the points at $A$ are on an arc of width $N^{-13}$, those at $B$ on an arc of width $N{-9}$ and those at $C$ on an arc of width $N^{-11}$; and further the angle at $B$ is $\pi/2-N^{-7}$, then all triangles $A_iA_jB_k, B_iB_jC_k$ and $C_iC_jA_k$ are acute.

Comment: "An IMO question from 1970" is awfully vague.  Could you give more pointers, and/or the statement?

Comment: this question is fully answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592964/how-many-acute-triangles-can-be-formed-by-100-points-in-a-plane .

Comment: Yes, my question iis to fill in the gap between 2/3 and 5/9

Comment: @LSpice It's not vague at all.  There's only one IMO each year, 
consisting of six problems.  It's easy enough to locate online.  
Problem 6 reads 
"In a plane there are $100$ points, no three of which are collinear. 
Consider all possible triangles having these point as vertices. 
Prove that no more than $70\%$ of these triangles are acute-angled."  
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1970_IMO_Problems

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, certainly you are right and I am wrong.  Despite my quoting it accurately, I read it as "from the 1970's".

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509657/what-proportion-of-triangles-are-acute and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892862/find-the-maximum-percentage-of-acute-angled-triangles-in-a-plane-with-100-poin and http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/ObtuseTriangle.shtml

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I am pretty sure the MSE answers establish the upper bound of 66.675%, by drawing a contradiction, but don't provide a pattern of points with a slightly lower percentage.